# Is it enough to check for BOOL status or should we check for Error as well?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8, nserror, touch-id

When a method returns a BOOL and Error at the same time, Is it enough to check for BOOL status or should we add the additional condition for Error as well?

For example, Following method returns a BOOL and error if any.

`-(BOOL)canEvaluatePolicy:(LAPolicy)policy error:(NSError * __autoreleasing *)error;`

Now should I write

```
 BOOL biometricsAvailable = [context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error];
    available = (error == nil && biometricsAvailable);
```

or

`BOOL biometricsAvailable = [context canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&error];`

is enough?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, checking the return value should be enough. But when `NO` is returned, you can have a look at the `error` variable to see why.

Apple have stated that you should check the return value of the method and only when this is `NO` or `nil` can you check the error, 
since the SDK could put some weird value in the `error` variable.

See the document [Programming with Objective-C - Dealing with Errors](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html)

Answer (score 3):

It is clearly described in the documentation here; https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/LocalAuthentication/Reference/LAContext_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/LAContext/canEvaluatePolicy:error:,

> Return Value
>
> `true` if the policy can be evaluated, `false` otherwise.
>
> Parameters
>
> `policy`
>   The policy to evaluate.
>    `error`
>   On input, a pointer to an error object. If an error occurs, this pointer is set to an actual error object containing the error information. You may specify `nil` for this parameter if you do not want the error information.

So, this means that the Boolean return value tells you if the evaluation was successful. And in case that fails, your error object will be set, which will have a description about the failure.

Answer (score 1):

Define "enough". For what?

The contract of the convention is that if there is a problem, `NO` should be returned and if you passed in an `NSError` pointer it'll be populated. If you want to do something with the error, you have to check it, but the convention says that there'll never be a case where the error is provided but `YES` is returned (if `YES` is returned the pointer shouldn't even be touched), or where `NO` is returned and there's no error. This convention is everywhere in Cocoa and has been stable for decades, and since Swift just based their error handling on this model, I think this is even less likely to change.

Comment: One clarification, though: the convention does not guarantee that the error pointer will be `nil` if the direct return value is "success". Thus you should not use presence of an error object to determine whether the method succeeded.

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer to mention that when `YES` is the return value the error pointer should not be considered at all by the method.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases are different. It Depends on your requirement.

If you use only `BOOL` then you only get the status of the request. Whether it is failed or succeed and based on that you can perform task.But you won't be able to know what is the error.

To know what exactly the error is you should go with with first method. If you want to know.